# Java code/library to merge continous CIDR blocks

Tags: java, cidr, netmask

is there any java api or library which can be used to merge multiple continuous cidr blocks.

For eg:

```
209.152.214.112/30
209.152.214.116/31
209.152.214.118/31
```

can be merged into `209.152.214.112/29`.
But below cidr can not be merged since they are not continuous.

```
209.152.214.112/30
209.152.214.116/32
209.152.214.118/31
```

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for this question.

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu I'm not sure about that. Software Recommendations SE is moderated even more strictly than Stack Overflow. If the OP wants to post there, they should read the [SoftwareRecs question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336) first. Otherwise it's going to be a disappointment.

Comment: might be a starting point: https://gist.github.com/denji/17e30bddb9ce9e50294a

Comment: Just rephrase the question into "How do I merge continuous CIDR blocks" and perhaps show an idea you already might have how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

There is a library available in Java for this. The [open-source IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) has methods for merging addresses and subnets into prefix block subnets.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of the IPAddress library.

The following method "merge" shows the code, relying on the method mergeToPrefixBlocks from the library:

```
static IPAddress[] merge(String strs[]) {
    List<String> strList = Arrays.asList(strs);
    // convert first
    IPAddress first = new IPAddressString(strList.get(0)).getAddress(); 
    // convert remaining
    IPAddress others[] = strList.subList(1, strList.size()).stream().map(str -> new IPAddressString(str).getAddress()).toArray(IPAddress[]::new);  

    // merge first with remaining
    return first.mergeToPrefixBlocks(others);
}
```

The method can be demonstrated with your examples:

```
    System.out.println("blocks are " + Arrays.asList(merge(new String[] {"209.152.214.112/30", "209.152.214.116/31", "209.152.214.118/31"})));
    System.out.println("blocks are " + Arrays.asList(merge(new String[] {"209.152.214.112/30", "209.152.214.116/32", "209.152.214.118/31"})));
```

The output is:

```
blocks are [209.152.214.112/29]
blocks are [209.152.214.116/32, 209.152.214.118/31, 209.152.214.112/30]
```